# _findfirst failure with .. path

Tags: c, regex, file, io

Why `_findfirst` returns -1 with `..\*.txt` search pattern

```
struct _finddata_t c_file;
hFile = _findfirst("..\\*.txt", &c_file);
```

But processes `..\*` correctly?

Comment: Are there any txt files in the current working directory of your process?

Comment: there are no txt files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_findfirst` works correctly when passed `"..\\*.txt"`. The fact that it returns `-1` indicates that there are no text files in the directory above your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Our comments:

> Are there any txt files in the current working directory of your process? – H2CO3
>
> there are no txt files – Chesnokov Yuriy

That's why. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzxfzac.aspx):

> Provide information about the first instance of a file name that matches the file specified in the filespec argument.

No surprise, no magic.

Comment: I'm looking over list of directories for files matching a pattern. It needs to handle ENOENT case I presume

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy Yes, or whatever, I actually meant "the directory which you are searching", so it's `..`, but that doesn't change the fact that the function works fine, it's just that there aren't any files matching the search criterion.

Comment: thank you I missed the documentation that there should be files matching the query. how I was able to elude that error before?